# Read an rdf model from a String

Tags: java, rdf, jena

I'm using Jena, and I want to create a model and then read its contents from a String that contains RDF.  For instance:

```xml
String s= "<rdf:RDF 
    xmlns:res="http://www.w3.org/2005/sparql-results#" xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"> 
   <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://www.w3.org/2005/sparql-results#ResultSet">  
    <res:solution rdf:nodeID="r0"/> 
    <res:solution rdf:nodeID="r1"/> 
    <res:solution rdf:nodeID="r2"/> 
   </rdf:Description>
   </rdf:RDF>";
```

At the moment, I use these instructions:

```java
    Model rdf = ModelFactory.createDefaultModel(); 
    InputStream in = FileManager.get().open(s);
    if (in == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("File: " + s+ " not found");
    }
    rdf.read(in, "");
```

These work only when `s` is the filename (such as `s="./myFile.rdf"`), and not when I put the String that contains the whole RDF.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Model.read(String,...)` methods use the string argument as a filename.  To read RDF content from a string, you can create a ByteArrayInputStream and use the `Model.read(InputStream,...)` methods.  For instance, using [Model.read(InputStream in, String base)](http://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/jena/com/hp/hpl/jena/rdf/model/Model.html#read%28java.io.InputStream,%20java.lang.String%29) to read your model, and then writing it back out in Turtle:

```java
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;

import com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.Model;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.ModelFactory;

public class ReadModelFromString {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final String modelText = "\n"
                + "<rdf:RDF \n"
                + "    xmlns:res=\"http://www.w3.org/2005/sparql-results#\" xmlns:rdf=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#\"> \n"
                + "  <rdf:Description rdf:about=\"http://www.w3.org/2005/sparql-results#ResultSet\">\n"
                + "    <res:solution rdf:nodeID=\"r0\"/>\n"
                + "    <res:solution rdf:nodeID=\"r1\"/>\n"
                + "    <res:solution rdf:nodeID=\"r2\"/>\n"
                + "  </rdf:Description>\n" + "</rdf:RDF>";
        final Model model = ModelFactory.createDefaultModel();
        model.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(modelText.getBytes()), null);
        model.write(System.out, "TTL");
    }
}
```

produces:

```
@prefix res:     <http://www.w3.org/2005/sparql-results#> .
@prefix rdf:     <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> .

res:ResultSet
      res:solution
              [] ;
      res:solution
              [] ;
      res:solution
              [] .
```

Comment: Thank you a lot Joshua. In fact, the String s (initialy written in one line) was only given as an  example, and to make it more readable I wrote it in multiple lines without adding "+"
Regardless, your code is perfect and it works nice, thank you again

Comment: Glad to be of help!  I use this technique a lot, especially when writing unit tests.  As an additional piece of advice, if you're going to use RDF content from strings, you might consider writing it in Turtle (which is much easier to write by hand, and to read by eye), in which case you'll want [Model.read(InputStream,String,String)](http://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/jena/com/hp/hpl/jena/rdf/model/Model.html#read(java.io.InputStream, java.lang.String, java.lang.String)) so that you can specify the language ("TTL").

Comment: Yes I agree with you, TTL is much easier to read then rdf/xml.